# Execution failed for task ':app:processPromoGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name, even when all folders and name are matching

Tags: android

I feel stuck (ಥ﹏ಥ) with the

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processPromoGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.cfhero.android.promo'
```

despite I double checked my build variant version package name are matching. Any idea? ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

app/src/promo/google-services.json

```
    {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "286942545508",
    "firebase_url": "https://cfhero-promo.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "cfhero-promo",
    "storage_bucket": "cfhero-promo.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:286942545508:android:32034c7882c4e592ec8171",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.cfhero.android.promo"
        }
      },
      ...
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

app/src/build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cfhero.android"
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 160
        versionName "1.3.0(160)-SNAPSHOT"
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
        promo {
            ...
            applicationIdSuffix ".promo"
            versionNameSuffix "-promo"
        }
```

versions:
`classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4"`
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the older library:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
}
```

This move fixed the issue in my case.

Comment: wow,it worked...hopefully they will fix it in next library update, the fact you have to downgrade the library (and possibly stuck with different bugs)  is terrifying

Comment: I tried the latest version which is working and it's "4.2.0"

Comment: Thanks for the information :) I hope that they will make the newest version stable too.